# Memory Leak in SharePoint Code?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, memory, memory-leaks, spweb

I am just wondering how to find out a memory leak in a code. 
I am working on a code written by someone else and been told that it has a memory leak. 
I am going through the code to see if it has a memory leak.

does following code has memory leak. 
do i need to close the SPWEB objects here.

```
     private bool isSubSite()
    {

        SPWeb currWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPWeb rootWeb = currWeb.Site.RootWeb;

        if (currWeb.ID != rootWeb.ID)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry, I've just noticed you're getting `SpContext.Current.Web`. That is a shared resource, and thus you should not call dispose on it, as pointed out by @Servy. Let the framework take care of that for you.

---

You need to dispose of the `SPWeb` objects. You can either call `Dispose` yourself after you no longer need them, or you can use the `using` statement, which automatically disposes the object for you:

```
  private bool isSubSite()
{

    using (SpWeb currWeb = SpContext.Current.Web){
        using (SPWeb rootWeb = currWeb.Site.RootWeb){

            if (currWeb.ID != rootWeb.ID)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is no problem returning inside the `using`, as this code will be translated into a `try...finally` code block later with the call to dispose inside the `finally` block, thus making sure it will be executed regardless of function returning or exceptions thrown.

Also, note that you should not call neither `Dispose` or `Close` on shared `SpWeb` objects. As this is not the case, you can call them safely.

Comment: Disposing SPContext.Current.Web isn't a great idea.

Comment: You should delete this, it's now marked as the accepted answer and you've just ruined poor @user388969 's day.

Comment: Well, I've edited it with the right information before he accepted it as the answer. So I don't know how I ruined his day, sorry.  
If it would be me though, I would mark @Servy 's answer as the answer for the question because he rightly answered it before me. But - obviously - I do not get to choose that.

Answer (score 5):

No, that code does not have a memory leak.

No, you should not be disposing of those `SPWeb` objects.  If you do dispose of them then when those `SPWeb` objects are used on subsequent requests, or in subsequent locations of the current request, it will fail.  The framework code created the `SPWeb` object and assigned it to the current context is responsible for disposing of it.

Answer (score -2):

Simplify the code to:

```
private bool isSubSite()
    { return SPContext.Current.Web.ID != currWeb.Site.RootWeb.ID;}
```

No way from looking at your code to determine whether it could be a source of a memory leak (but the code above only uses temporary references).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of whether or not the code has a leak, nor does it provide any form of explanation.